# Why @State var used when View isn't getting updated

Tags: swift, swiftui

My understanding of `@State` variable is whenever state changes within a `View`, we need to use `@State` variable. However, consider example below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var image: Image?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            image?
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
        }
        .onAppear(perform: loadImage)
    }

    func loadImage() {
        image = Image("Example.png")
    }
}
```

As far as my limited knowledge goes I am not changing any `View` by virtue of toggle switch or button etc. then why `@State` variable being used? Why can't we just write: `private var image: Image?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VStack will contain an `EmptyView()` if the image is nil. In that sense, your view is changed.

Think about it: Until `loadImage` is called, the image is nil and the view already initialized!

Comment: My apologies for asking basics, am just unable to apply my learning in this context, I haven't come across optional views so that's confusing me. a) When we say `@State private var image: Image?`, what exactly that means from a SwiftUI `View` perspective? b) What does `image?` in `VStack` means? If it doesn't exists, from where is it coming?

Comment: `Image?` is an  optional image, possibly being `nil`. In your code, it does not exist unti the line `image = Image("Example.png")`. As that line is not called on initialization of the struct, but later (at `onAppear`) , you will change the struct, hence you need `@State`:)

Comment: np. select it as the correct answer if you don't mind;)